# How to express exponential of a variable in docplex?

Tags: numpy, variables, cplex, exponential, docplex

I need to define a constraint as follows:

mdl.add_constraints(p_pg[plan, segment] == np.exp(u_pg[plan, segment] for plan in range(1, p+1) for segment in range(1, g+1))

In this constraint both p_pg and u_pg are variable and are defined as mdl.continuous_var_dict. However I get the following error:
loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Var which has no callable exp method

Can anyone help how to define this constraint?

Answer (score 0):

exp is not linear so you could either try to do a [piecewise linear approximation](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/opltipsandtricks/blob/master/interpolatewithpiecewiselinear.mod) or use Constraint Programming within CPLEX.

See this [example](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoononlinear.py) in [Easy optimization with python](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer/)

```
from docplex.cp.model import CpoModel

mdl = CpoModel(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(0,1000,name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(0,1000,name='nbBus30')
mdl.add(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300)

#non linear objective
mdl.minimize(mdl.exponent(nbbus40)*500 + mdl.exponent(nbbus30)*400)

msol=mdl.solve()

print(msol[nbbus40]," buses 40 seats")
print(msol[nbbus30]," buses 30 seats")
```